# Set constrain violation code with annotation

Tags: validation, symfony

[ConstrainViolation](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolation.html) class has very handy (readonly) property `code`. It can be set when building violations with validation callback like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    // Some test validation.
    if (/* blah blah */)
    {
        $context
            ->buildViolation('validation.error.message')
            ->atPath('test')
            // This is the return code for use in calls API
            ->setCode(6)
            ->addViolation()
        ;
    }
}
```

It's very handy when building APIs that return status codes instead of human readable messages. But is it possible to set this `code` property with validators defined with annotations? Or maybe at least somehow add them inside validation callback?